# Bootstrap 3: How to get a lower column (default xs/mobile layout) to sit higher in larger viewports

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My issue is with my non-mobile layout. I have four columns. Here is their order (the widths are for sm/md/lg):

```
A(3-wide)
B(9-wide)
C(9-wide)
D(3-wide)
```

Column B is a big, variable-height column. So column A is always going to be shorter than B. When the viewport expands, my issue is that I can't get D to sit underneath A, even though they're both 3-wide columns and there is empty/unfilled space below A.

What I want:

```
BBB A
BBB D
BBB
CCC
```

What I have right now:

```
BBB A
BBB
BBB
CCC D
```

No matter what I try with push/pull, nesting, etc., D will not jump up into that space below A.

Here is my code, stripped down to the basics:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right">
            <p>(A) Right-aligned, 3-wide div that's pretty short</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 pull-left">
            <h1>(B) Left-aligned, large variable height content div.</h1>
            <h1>(B)</h1>
            <h1>(B)</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <h3>(C) Left-aligned smaller content div</h3>
            <h3>(C)</h3>
            <h3>(C)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <h4>(D) Right-aligned, 3-wide div that I want to go below the first 3-wide div</h4>
            <h4>(D)</h4>
            <h4>(D)</h4>
            <h4>(D)</h4>
            <h4>(D)</h4>
            <h4>(D)</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also drew it on paper, if that helps visualize the desired layout:

[image: scheme]

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need exactly 4 columns, you can use this solution:

1. Wrap `B` and `C` blocks into an additional block.
2. Apply the `float: right` property to the block `A` when the screen width becomes 786px or more. I've defined a new special class for this purpose.

[image: result]

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/ckLqrfmp/

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
#A, #B, #C, #D { 
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
#A { background: #c69; min-height:  50px; }
#B { background: #9c6; min-height: 150px; }
#C { background: #69c; min-height: 100px; }
#D { background: #ff0; min-height: 250px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="A" class="col-sm-3 pull-sm-right">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="B" class="col-xs-12">B</div>
        <div id="C" class="col-xs-12">C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="D" class="col-sm-3">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I won't recommend this solution. There are two reasons for that: a) this solution introduce 15 columns grid (3 + 9 + 3) and Botstrap is written (and tested) for 12 columns grid. I can not stress enough how much is important for developers who use frameworks to use it in way as suggested with docs. This is not me being rigid, I simple waste to many hours to debug hacks like this. b) this solution does not address main problem that user Peter Simones is dealing with: that is gap caused with elements which have float: left/right. For more details search with "float vertical gap issue"

Comment: @Danko Thanks for feedback. I've used standard 12-columns grid, [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) and [nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). All these features are described in the Bootstrap documentation. My `.pull-sm-float` class is based on Bootstrap's [quick floats](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky if I could upvote this 10 times, I would. HUGE thank you. This made my day. (Solution works perfectly.)

Comment: @PeterSimones Glad to be helpful :) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score -1):

Mentioned gap is result of how floats works. Common solution is [masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) . In other words, you can't fix it with css, but with javascript. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would appreciate explanation why this answer is downvoted

Comment: It was not my voice. I guess, a possible reason is that the problem **can** be solved by CSS. I should be grateful if you share version why my answer was downrated.